# jQuery - change index of list item

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the index of a list item in jquery by doing the following:

```
 $(this).index(2);
```

This does not appear to work correctly.

Is the only way to achieve this by using insertBefore/insertAfter?

Comment: You could collect the list items in an array and do `splice()` and change the "index" of something, if you get the idea and that might help. With objects I guess the insertion order does not work cross-browser!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index()` simply returns the index, it does not set it, so you have to use a method that actually changes the DOM to move the element around.

```
$(this).siblings().eq(1).after(this);
```